# Flutter Stack's child is transparent while using linear gradient

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using a stack, where the save 60% off widget is on top of the container with white background. I am using gradient on the discount container. I want the gradient to be solid , but as you can see in the image, it is semi-transparent and we can see the white background under it.

My stack code is:

```
 Container(
      width: width * 0.38,
      height: 250,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 20,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                width: width * 0.38,
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height: 35.h),
                    buildProductPrice(product, _intros),
                    buildCheckMark(product),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: buildDiscountText(product, _intros)),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

buildDiscountText widget:

```
       return Container(
        height: 40,
        width: 100,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(0.8),
                Color(0xffCE41FD),
              ],
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        child: Text(
          'SAVE $_rounded %',
          style: _saveTextStyle,
        ),
      );
```

To get solid background I could wrap buildDiscountTextWidget with Container and provide same gradient and do this 2,3 times but I don't think that is the proper way.

[here is the screen shot of the widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN803.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `.withOpacity(0.8)` from the end of                 `Colors.lightBlue.withOpacity(0.8)`

Answer (score 1):

Change buildDiscountText widget as follows:

```
return Container(
    height: 40,
    width: 100,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Colors.lightBlue, //remove opacity
            Color(0xffCE41FD),
          ],
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
    child: Text(
      'SAVE $_rounded %',
      style: _saveTextStyle,
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I added opacity to get desired gradient. I didn't realise that it was causing transparency.

Comment: So did you get satisfied result?